# Moving current document management system to sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint-designer, oracle

Currently we have an Oracle DB2 database connected to a service bus. We send proxy requests and receive responses.

I'm wondering how do I go about configuring this setup to work with sharepoint?

Ideally we want to be able to load documents from the DB2 database/BUS and save back into it.

Any advice welcome. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would encourage you to look at the client object model for interacting with SharePoint.  There are some rich APIs that will allow you to add and interact with content in SharePoint.

Client Object Model Reference:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee857094(v=office.14).aspx

Upload a document with Client OM
http://www.learningsharepoint.com/2010/07/12/programmatically-upload-document-using-client-object-model-sharepoint-2010/

Comment: thanks Mike. I see Microsoft Biztalk server allows some connections, do I need this Biztalk server?

Comment: You will need to be able to execute the integration code from somewhere, I assume within your service bus.  BizTalk is not required, but could be used.  I don't think it would make sense to implement BizTalk though if you already have a service bus/orchestration tool.

Comment: just another question. If I already have java proxy's do I create some new proxies with REST or Client Object Model. Saw this link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff798339.aspx . Thanks for helping

Comment: You can call those services directly from the other system even if they are in Java.  Depending on the final details of the scenario, you could possibly need a proxy for the code that adds the file to SharePoint, but you should be able to do it directly through the available services.

Comment: at the moment I have say a RequestManager.java that fires proxy requests out to a DB2 bus and receives responses. We are looking to be able to send the same requests to the sharepoint server and receive responses. Can you advise on what would be required? thanks